# Priority is currently in use when deploying CDK

Tags: python, aws-cdk

I define cdk :

```
priority = 0
for path in targets.keys():
    listener.add_targets(
        "TargetGroup" + path + name,
        port=80,
        path_pattern=path + "*",
        priority = priority + 2,
        targets=[targets[path]],
        health_check=healthCheck(path),
    )
```

When deploy, i got this:

`Priority '2' is currently in use (Service: AmazonElasticLoadBalancingV2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: PriorityInUse; Request ID: da53a5c6-9856-4e43-b5d8-29ff90d9ab17)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, I define random for priority :

```
    ALB_RULE_PRIORITY_RANGE = 1, 50000
    for path in targets.keys():
        listener.add_targets(
            "TargetGroup" + path + name,
            port=80,
            path_pattern=path + "*",
            priority=int(random.randint(*ALB_RULE_PRIORITY_RANGE)),
            targets=[targets[path]],
            health_check=healthCheck(path),
        )
```

Comment: Which is a really, really sad indictment of CDK that you have to fall back on random and hope for no collisions in what's supposed to be for automation. But yeah - this is basically the only way.